# ListWheelScrollView change item active position

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

ListWheelScrollView change item active position

change position to top

```
ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate(
          itemExtent: 30,
          childDelegate: ListWheelChildBuilderDelegate(
              childCount: 50,
              builder: (context , index){
                return Text(index.toString());
              }
          ),
        )
```

[image]

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is no documented property for setting the initial item position in ListWheelScrollView but here is the trick to set your initial item to top of the view.
You should set a controller with initialItem to the ListWheelScrollView like this:

> _controller = FixedExtentScrollController(initialItem:15 );

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      final FixedExtentScrollController _controller = FixedExtentScrollController(initialItem:15 );
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
            body: MediaQuery.removePadding(
              context: context,
              removeTop: true,
              child: ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate(
                itemExtent: 30,controller: _controller,
                childDelegate: ListWheelChildBuilderDelegate(
                    childCount: 50,
                    builder: (context , index){
                      return Text(index.toString());
                    }
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

[image]